# redirect from new action to create action with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to design a shopping cart. i.e a customer shopping online adds a product to their trolley.
I want to go straight to create action from my new action without going to `new.html.erb` with pre-set values in my params

Here is what I have so far:

```
@trolley_id += 1 
redirect_to :controller => 'trolleys', :action => 'create', :id => @trolley_id, :something => 'else', method: :post
```

This redirects me to my index action

Comment: you can't really redirect with a post request, what are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to input values into my table without using a form. i.e a customer shopping online adds a product to trolley.

Comment: I can't think of a solution from the backend, you either render a javascript that does that post request, or do the creation in the backend, like from another action and serve that action instead of new maybe

Comment: It is unclear why you are going to the `new` action at all if you don't actually want it. What are you trying to do? Why don't you just post directly to `create` from wherever action you are getting `new` from?

Comment: that would be even better. can post example of a way i can do that with param values.

Answer (score 0):

To do this with javascript templates, it would look like this:

**view**

```
= form_form Trolley.new, remote: true do
  -# form goes here
```

The remote true will submit it as javascript, which will try to render a javascript template.

Your create action can either `render :create` or let Rails render your template automatically. Since it came in as a javascript request, Rails will render the template with format js.

**trolleys/create.js.erb**

```
var html = "<%= j render 'trolley_row', trolley: @trolley %>
$('table.trolleys body').append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve my problem. I created a form in my Product_controller#show that will go straight to my Trolley_controller#create and create an entry in my Trolleys table

```
    <%= simple_form_for [@product, @trolley] do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :quantity, collection: 1..12, prompt: "select quantity" %>
        <%= f.input :product_id, :as => :hidden %>
        <%= f.input :user_id, :as => :hidden %>
        <%= f.button :submit, "Add to Basket" %>
 <% end %>
```